# How can I use Applescript or any other utility to send a daily text message to my bank?

Tags: applescript, messages, ical

I have searched and I find a lot of results for specific methods of sending an iMessage with Applescript, but they all seem to contain extraneous code for specific needs that I don't need. I'm wondering how I can schedule automated text messages based on a repeating time. For instance: text my wife every morning at 9am, or text my bank every morning at 5am.

So the specific help I need is (I think):

- how do I send an iMessage with Applescript,
- and how do I schedule an Applescript to repeat daily or weekly etc. at a given time?

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer to this via google. This Applescript will send the iMessage:

```
tell application "Messages"
          send "Text of Message" to buddy "+61mobilenumber" of service "E:*icloud email address*"
end tell
```

I saved that as an app, then set a recurring iCal event that will open the app at the time I set every day. Voila! Beautiful.